# Haskell type error: Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of `show' from the context (Num a)

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, typeclass, xmonad

I am configuring xmonad, and since I have to start a couple of dzen instances, I decided that it could be better to use a function that takes the parameters for x and y position, width, height and text align:

```
-- mydzen.hs

import Data.List

-- | Return a string that launches dzen with the given configuration.
myDzen :: Num a  => a -> a -> a -> Char -> String -> String

myDzen y x w ta e =
        intercalate " "
            [ "dzen2"
            , "-x"  , show x
            , "-w"  , show w
            , "-y"  , show y
            , "-h"  , myHeight
            , "-fn" , quote myFont
            , "-bg" , quote myDBGColor
            , "-fg" , quote myFFGColor
            , "-ta" , [ta]
            , "-e"  , quote e
            ]

quote :: String -> String
quote x = "'" x "'"

-- dummy values
myHeigth = "20"
myFont = "bitstream"
myDBGColor = "#ffffff"
myFFGColor = "#000000"

Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of `show'
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for
             myDzen :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> Char -> String -> String
  at mydzen.hs:(5,1)-(17,13)
Possible fix:
  add (Show a) to the context of
    the type signature for
      myDzen :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> Char -> String -> String
In the expression: show x
In the second argument of `intercalate', namely
  `["dzen2", "-x", show x, "-w", ....]'
In the expression:
  intercalate " " ["dzen2", "-x", show x, "-w", ....]
```

Obviously, deleting the signature, or changing `Num a` for `Show a` solves the issue, but I can't understand why. The 'arguments' `x`, `w` and `y` are *supposed* to be almost any kind of numbers (`100`, `550.2`, `1366 * 0.7` ecc).

I'm new to haskell and until now I haven't been able to (clearly) understand the error or find what's wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Previously, `Show` and `Eq` were superclasses of `Num` and the code would compile.

In the new GHC, from version 7.4, this has changed, now `Num` does not depend on `Show` and `Eq`, so you need to add them to signatures.

The reason is separation of concerns - there are numeric types with no sensible equality and show function (computable reals, rings of functions).

Comment: Thanks, even when you didn't give the "exact" answer, gave me the background (and history) to understand which was the origin of the error message :)

Answer (score 7):

Not all numbers are showable (standard types like `Int` or `Integer` are, but you could have defined your own type; how would compiler know?) You’re using `show x` in your function — therefore, `a` must belong to `Show` typeclass. You can change your signature to `myDzen :: (Num a, Show a) => a -> a -> a -> Char -> String -> String` and get rid of the error.

Answer (score 3):

`show` is not part of the `Num` type class — to be able to use it, you have to add `Show` constraint alongside the `Num` one:

```
myDzen :: (Num a, Show a) => a -> a -> a -> Char -> String -> String
```